# Links stop working at the tablet viewport ( 768px to 991px ) in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink, viewport

I really can't explain why this is happening but I am building a WP theme in BS3, for some reason, on the tablet viewport (768 to 991px) my links stop working. They are not clickable, tappable, tab-able, etc.

What causes this strange phenomena? How do I even diagnose when my site is W3C Compliant?

Ugh... the horror!

I really don't have code to support this, but I could paste my entire page on here. I will do that on request, or my CSS file, etc.

Comment: something is overlapping them (probably not visible).. making them un-clickable..

Comment: Too much code is better than no code at all. My initial instinct is that a transparent element is covering the links.

Comment: updated og post with code link.  Thanks folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using bootstrap .col-* DIVs should reside in .row DIVs and in turn .container DIVs. I can see in your html that you have 2 top level DIVs with a class of .col-*, and they have different screen sizes associated with them. Your footer DIV has a class of 'col-lg-12 footer area' which means when it gets below 991px it will stop floating, while the rest of your content floats, which is whats causing the issue.

If you change the footer class to: 'col-sm-12 footer area' - this will solve the issue.

But what you ideally need to do is remove the col-sm-12 from your footer and page-wrap altogether and replace it with 'container' so they look like: `<div class="container footer area">`

Comment: Thanks James!!! Makes sense, not sure if I made it a "lg" by mistake but either way an error.